# How to correctly type Contentful EntryFieldTypes.AssetLink

Tags: reactjs, typescript, contentful

I'm stuck on a Typescript issue using Contentul. I hope anyone can point me in the right direction.

Contentful generated the following type interfaces for me based on the contenttypes I've setup in Contentful.

```
import type { ChainModifiers, Entry, EntryFieldTypes, EntrySkeletonType, LocaleCode } from "contentful";

export interface TypeBlendFields {
    title: EntryFieldTypes.Symbol;
    description: EntryFieldTypes.RichText;
    cover: EntryFieldTypes.AssetLink;
}

export type TypeBlendSkeleton = EntrySkeletonType<TypeBlendFields, "blend">;
export type TypeBlend<Modifiers extends ChainModifiers, Locales extends LocaleCode> = Entry<TypeBlendSkeleton, Modifiers, Locales>;
```

When using `client.getEntries()`, the JSON object contains all data that is needed, including the `cover` property and all nested properties (metadata, sys and fields for an image).

My issue is that Typescript does not know the type of these nested properties for `cover`. I'm not able to understand why though.

I've tried creating the following interface

```
export interface ICover {
  fields: {
    title: string,
    file: {
      fileName: string,
      contentType: string,
      details: {
        image: {
          width: number,
          height: number
        },
        size: number
      },
      url: string
    },
    description: string
  }
}
```

and use that

```
export interface TypeBlendFields {
    title: EntryFieldTypes.Symbol;
    description: EntryFieldTypes.RichText;
    cover: EntryFieldTypes.AssetLink;
}
```

I was able to use the properties without dot-notation like so `newEntries[0].fields!['file']['url']`, but I would like to use proper Typescript here.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind ... My interface `ICover` was correct but I was not using it correctly.

So, when looping over the JSON response object it's possible to transform the Contentful `item` to be of a specific type (or Interface). In my case, like this.

```
const entries = items.map(entry => {
  return entry.fields.cover as ICover
}
```

I hope this helps anyone dealing with the same issue.

Comment: But why we have to cast? The AssetLink type should do it.

Comment: Exactly my question, it should be know at this point. By casting, I've managed to make it work. Now looking for a better solution.